# What is my syntax error reading .wav file?

Tags: python-2.7, wav

I am coding in python and am trying get data from a .wav file so that I can perform a FFT and use that result to determine the freq of the note played.
This is what I have tried:

[image]

and this is the error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Do not post images of code, if the link dies the question will eventually become useless. It is much better to copy/paste.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error is that `/` is the math division operator (10/2, val1/val2) and needs numbers on either side, and opening a function call into a division with no numbers is a nonsense - invalid.

Your filename needs to be a string - enclosed in quotes.

```
harp = wave.open('/path/to/file', 'r')
```

(And it presumably needs to be `wave.open` not `wav.open`)

Answer (score 0):

Strings, such as the path to your file, need to be denoted by quotes (`'`s) or double quotes (`"`s):

```
harp = wav.open('/Users/williamwiess2/Desktop/Test 2/harp.wav', 'r');
# Here ---------^--------------------------------------------^
```